# set clear without none and must have clearance?

Tags: html, css

I have read spec [clear](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#propdef-clear),and can't think of how to set clear and not introduce clearance.
the spec only has one example when have clearance,But not say when not.

> If this hypothetical position of the element's top border edge is not past the relevant floats, then clearance is introduced, and margins collapse according to the rules in 8.3.1.

I think ,the element's top border edge must equal with float's(when one float element),so can't have example to understand clear and no clearance

eg1(height 1px)

```css
.floated {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.block {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.cleared {
  clear: left;
  background-color: silver;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floated">floated</div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="cleared">cleared</div>
```

---

eg2(height 0px)

```css
.floated {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.block {
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}

.cleared {
  clear: left;
  background-color: silver;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floated">floated</div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="cleared">cleared</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no clearance of the element if the element's top border edge is equal to or below any preceding float's *bottom margin edge* on the same side(s) as the clear.

In the following example, the div with class "cleared" is preceded by a floated element, is cleared on the same side, but has no clearance.

```css
.floated {
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:cyan;
 }
 .block {
   height :110px;
   background-color:green;
 }
 .cleared {
   clear: left;
   background-color:silver;
 }
```

```html
<div class="floated">floated</div>
<div class="block">A block</div>
<div class="cleared">cleared</div>
```

Whereas in this example, it has a clearance of 10px:

```css
.floated {
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:cyan;
 }
 .block {
   height :90px;
   background-color:green;
 }
 .cleared {
   clear: left;
   background-color:silver;
 }
```

```html
<div class="floated">floated</div>
<div class="block">A block</div>
<div class="cleared">cleared</div>
```

Comment: thanks,but why your first code satisfy this hypothetical position of the element's top border edge(.cleared) is not past the relevant floats(.floated),but not introduce clearance

Comment: I add two codes and find a strange strange phenomena
when .block set 1px then the margin top display(although introduce clearance),but set 0px  margin top not display.

Comment: @cando I guess you need to also consider margin collapsing here. When your element is height:0 its top and bottom margin will collpase and it's bottom margin will collapse with the cleared element and will also collapse with the body margin since its the first in-flow element. A total of 4 margin collapsed. Not sure by the way how to consider this result with clearance.